# CSS - I want desktop landscape orientation to ignore CSS styles - works for iOS, but PC won't ignore?

Tags: css

I'm using this line of code to implement my website layout in landscape on a mobile device:

```
    @media (orientation: landscape) and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
   // All my styles are here
    }
```

That being said, it works perfectly on iOS devices (desktop ignores the styles, mobile implements them), but on PC Desktops, it won't ignore the @media query, and puts the styles on the desktop site (which I definitely do not want!)

How can I get desktop PCs to ignore the @media styles?

Comment: This is the weird part, when I tried doing min or max width, the mobile device ignored the media css all together in landscape mode! @rozsazoltan

Comment: Use media queries to specify the desktop and the mobile resolutions.